# Select2 not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I just downloaded Select2 4.0.2.  However, I'm having a problem as stated in the example page, I tried adding

```
<select class="js-example-basic-single form-control" id="js-example-basic-single">
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

And this is what's included in the page. I've put this on the footer part.

```
<script src="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
<script src="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- Metis Menu Plugin JavaScript -->
<script src="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/bower_components/metisMenu/dist/metisMenu.min.js"></script>

<!-- Custom Theme JavaScript -->
<script src="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/dist/js/sb-admin-2.js"></script>    <script src="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>   
<script src="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/select2/js/select2.full.js"></script>   

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".js-example-basic-single").select2();
});
</script>
```

And of course, added the css unde `<head>`

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/hospital_ci/assets/select2/css/select2.css">
```

However, I am unable to show up the results. I have the following error
`select2.full.js:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined` and also `Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function`

Oh by the way, I am using `jQuery v2.1.4`

Answer (score 1):

Here is the block of code in select2 that is giving you the error:

```
if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    // AMD. Register as an anonymous module.
    define(['jquery'], factory);
} else if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    // Node/CommonJS
    factory(require('jquery')); // <-- Line 14
} else {
    // Browser globals
    factory(jQuery);
}
```

So it looks like it thinks you're using Node or CommonJS, and its testing it by checking the type of the `exports` variable.

Do you have an `exports` variable defined somewhere in your global scope? Perhaps one of the other libraries is defining the variable?

In your debug console you can inspect the value of `exports` to maybe get a hint at where its being defined. (Just type `exports` and push enter in the console, if it isn't `undefined` then that's your issue).